# WSDL wsimport lower upper case issue

Tags: java, wsdl, converters, uppercase, lowercase

There is a WSDL file sent by a third party web service.

Back in February, my teammate converted the WSDL into java (Not sure which tool they used because they are not here any more). Our large-scaled project was built based on that.

Recently the web service party updated the WSDL. I tried to convert the new WSDL using **wsimport**. Now the problem is the those converted java classes are not compatible with the code base any more due to the package name changes (from upper case to lower case).

For example, **import gov.services.food.api.DataCollection.Extensions.CaseClient** is now changed to **gov.services.food.api.datacollection.extensions.CaseClient**

My questions is:

Does the choice of WSDL 2 Java convertor tool cause this kind of lower/upper case changes or even other data structure changes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The lower case package name is probably better as it conforms to naming standards. Typically generated code includes the tool that generated it in the comments, I think it is very likely that the changes are caused by usng different tools.

Comment: I agree that we should follow the naming convention. However, since the capitalized package version was generated and used widely in my app back then. It's kind of risky to change them all now. 

And it seems like I can only use 'wsimport', since different conversion tool will generate different package structures, which also ends up changing all the packages across the code base.

Comment: Is that even possible the web service provider has changed their source codes from their end but sent us an mismatched WSDL?

Comment: What I meant 'mismatched' is just the upper/lower case mismatching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed!

The choice of different convertors does affect the java codes result. For the same convertor tool, different options that you pass in will also affect the result.

In my particular case, I used '**ant**' build tool.

the core part in my build.xml is:

```
<target name="wsdl2java">
    <java classname="org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java" classpathref="DSSClient.classpath" failonerror="true" fork="true">
        <arg value="${wsdl.url}/DEX_august_2015.wsdl" />
        <arg line="-v -D -a" />
        <arg line="-o ${wsdl.url}/generated" />
        <arg line="-O -1" />
    </java>
</target>
```

And of course combined with the necessary jars that WSDL2Java requires.

This should create the java codes with capitalized package names.